# Havig trouble with SPI in PIC24FJ256GB412

Tags: c, pic, spi, adc, pic24

I am trying to configure a PIC24FJ256GB412 to use the SPI interface with an ADC module(ADS114S08). And now, I can view data by oscilloscope(by measuring the SDI pin). But the SPI1BUFL didn't receive correct data(always received 0x01). Below is the relevant code that I am using to configure the SPI.

```
uint8_t    DATA_S[1000]; // SPI data buffer for Receiving
uint8_t    DATA1;        // SPI data buffer for Receiving
uint16_t   DATA_counter=0;

void System_Initial(void)
{
    //Setup IO
    TRISDbits.TRISD0  = 0; //SCLK
    TRISDbits.TRISD5  = 0; //ADC RESET
    TRISDbits.TRISD10 = 0; //ADC START
    TRISDbits.TRISD11 = 1; //ADC DRDY
    TRISFbits.TRISF3  = 1; //SDI
    TRISFbits.TRISF4  = 0; //SDO

    ANSELDbits.ANSELD0  = 0; //Digital pins
    ANSELDbits.ANSELD5  = 0;
    ANSELDbits.ANSELD10 = 0;
    ANSELDbits.ANSELD11 = 0;
    ANSELFbits.ANSELF3  = 0;
    ANSELFbits.ANSELF4  = 0;
    
    //Setup SPI
    //MCU operates in 16MHz, ADC internal clk 4MHz
    SPI1BRGL    = 1;      //Baud rate = 4MHz
    SPI1CON1L   = 0x8020; //8bit mode //SCLK enable //Master Mode
    SPI1CON1H   = 0x2000; //AUDEN=0
    SPI1CON2L   = 0x0007; //8bit data

    //Setup PPS    
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xBF);
    _RP11R  = _RPOUT_SCK1OUT; // RP11 -> SCK1.
    RPINR20bits.SDI1R = 16;   // RP16 -> SDI1.
    _RP10R  = _RPOUT_SDO1;    // RP10 -> SDO1.
    __builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
    
}

//SPI1 - Set ADS114S08
void SPI1_SetADC()
{
    //set PGA
    //Input MUX Register, address = 02h
    //Gain setting Register, address = 03h
    SPI1BUFL = 0x42; //WREG at 02h
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x01; //Two bytes
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x01; //02h //AINP = AIN0, AINN = AIN1
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x0B; //03h //PGA enabled, Gain = 011 =8
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    
    //set Mode
    //Data Rate Register, address = 04h
    //Reference Control Register, address = 05h
    SPI1BUFL = 0x44; //WREG at 04h
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x01; //Two bytes
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x14; //04h //Continuous conversion mode //0100 : 20 SPS
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x30; //05h
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
   
    //set Excitation Current Sources
    //Excitation Current Register1(IDACMAG), address = 06h
    //Excitation Current Register2(IDACMUX), address = 07h
    SPI1BUFL = 0x46; //WREG at 06h
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x01; //Two bytes
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0x05; //06h //IDAC = 0101 = 500uA
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    SPI1BUFL = 0xF0; //07h //use IDAC1 => AIN0
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
}

//SPI1 - RREG
void SPI1_RREG()
{ 
    SPI1BUFL = 0x20; //send RREG Command //read 00h
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);
    
    SPI1BUFL = 0x00; //1 byte
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1);

    SPI1BUFL = 0x0000; //send DUMMY data
    while( SPI1STATLbits.SPIBUSY==1); //Wait Data
    uint8_t register1=  SPI1BUFL; //get data
    DATA1  = register1;
    DATA_S[DATA_counter%1000] = register1;
}

int main(void)
{
    System_Initial();

    LATDbits.LATD10 = 0; //ADC START=0
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 0;  //ADC RESET=0 //Enter RESET Status
    
    uint32_t loop = 0;
    loop = 4*4;         //MCU 16Mhz, ADC internal clk 4Mhz
    while (loop--);     //wait 4clk => ADS114S08 tw(RSL)
    LATDbits.LATD5 = 1; //ADC RESET low -> high //Enter Standby Mode
    
    loop=4096*4;
    while (loop--);     //wait 4096clk => ADS114S08 td(RSSC)
    
    SPI1_SetADC();      //set ADC Configuration
    LATDbits.LATD10 = 1; //START high -> Start Conversion

    //main while
    while(1)
    {
        DATA_counter++;
        SPI1_RREG();
    }
}
```

**bold**
*italic*

> 

As mentioned above, I can see data on SDI pin by oscilloscope.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZDcA.png)
And another data test.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Hwb.png)

By the waveform that we can see on the oscilloscope. The ADC module probably works the right way.

But... Let's see the MPLAB IDE side.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGnh8.png)
I can't get the right data(SPI1BUF = 0x0001). I have tried changing baudrate lower. But the result is no different. Is there a parameter I'm missing? Thanks for your help.

**------------------------------------------0530-----------------------------------------------**

Hi Craig, I have tried the code.

```
SPI1BUFL = 0x20; //send RREG Command //read 00h
while(SPI1STATLbits.SPITBF); // wait until the transmit buffer is empty

SPI1BUFL = 0x00; //set 1 byte
while(SPI1STATLbits.SPITBF); // wait until the transmit buffer is empty

uint8_t register1=0;
SPI1BUFL = 0x00; //send DUMMY data
while(!SPI1STATLbits.SPIRBF); //hang until data is received
register1 =  SPI1BUFL; //get data
```

The results were no difference. And I recorded it.

Oscilloscope:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZDcA.png)

IDE:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Hwb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGnh8.png)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct status bits? SPI is 4 wire, full duplex. I would expect a different status bit for Tx and Rx data, etc. You're using `SPIBUSY` but other examples use `SPITBF` and `SPIRBF`. From a web search on: `SPI1STATLbits`, amongst others see: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1096047.aspx and https://www.thisisant.com/forum/viewthread/6948

Comment: Hi Craig, thank you very much for your reply, you reminded me of an important idea, but I don't have a circuit board to test at the moment. If I do I'll let you know the results.

Comment: Hi @Craig , I have tried some code testing. Please see the record at question.

Comment: Just a guess, based on some of the web search results. They talk about "enhanced mode". If it's on, `SPIRBF` is only valid after 8 bytes have been received [device has a H/W FIFO?]. Turning it off makes it work. Also, you could try different dummy values to see if the readback on `SPI1BUFL` tracks the value (e.g. if so, it's just giving back what you wrote to it--not what you want).

Comment: Also, it can be more about how the _device_ responds, so from a search on: `ADS114S08 SPI` we have: https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters-group/data-converters/f/data-converters-forum/874470/ads114s08-can-not-read-temperature-over-spi-from-ads114s08

Comment: Hi @Craig , I already set the SPI1CON1L bit 0=0 (Enhanced Buffer Enable bit, 0 = Enhanced Buffer mode is disabled). Also tried the different dummy data, like 0x0A, 0xFF... And the SDI was the same results(0x00).

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/support/data-converters-group/data-converters/f/data-converters-forum/874470/ads114s08-can-not-read-temperature-over-spi-from-ads114s08  referenced it. I also already set the Global chop disable. It's the same results whether this bit set 1 or 0.

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1035784.aspx There, OP has some code that got fixed in the forum. It uses `__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);` and sets up some more things. Different baud rate (`BRG`). See the `SPI_TXRX` function. It spins on `!SPITBE` and then `!SPIRBF` It seems to always write a byte and read a byte, but you do: write, write, read. Also, `LATBbits`? In `SPI1_SetADC`, you're doing a lot of inline spin/write. I'd put that into a function or macro to tidy up, similar to link's `SPI_TXRX`

Comment: This may not matter depending upon the initial state, but the link does spin_on_bit,write_data but you do write_data,spin_on_bit

Comment: Hi @Craig, all the above I have tried and the result without any progress...

Comment: So I tried this. I add counter into the while like this...

Comment: while( !SPI1STATLbits.SPIRBF) 
    {
        SPI_loop++;
    } //hang until data is received

Comment: The counter 「SPI_loop」 is always zero...seems like SPI read registers never work.

Comment: Thank you all. I solved the problem by https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1208598.aspx

Comment: Hi @jmoedyk . Ok I’ll add answer later. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SPI should clear SPI1BUFL every time as you transmit data.
So I try the code like this.

```
    uint8_t SPI_EXCH(uint8_t data)
    {
       SPI1BUFL = data; // write to buffer for TX
       while(!SPI1STATLbits.SPIRBF); // wait for transfer to complete
       return SPI1BUFL; // read the received value
    }
```

And every time you try to do an SPI exchange, use the function above.